# calculating code runtime in highly optimized code

Tags: c++, optimization, iar

I'm working on Cortex M3 and using IAR EWARM. I use the `DWT_DYCCNT` for timing calculation. The problem is when I optimize the code for speed (using the compiler options), I lose the value of `DWT_DYCCNT` while debugging. The code is in C and C++. I also tried printing the value of the variable using `printf` but that also returns errors.

I tried making the variable `volatile`, but that also doesnt help.

While debugging I always get `unknown value` for this variable.

I want to know how to calculate the timing of a code in a code which has been optimized for speed and not lose the value of variables. How can I force the compiler to retain value of these variables?

EDIT:

```
     volatile int count = 0;
        volatile unsigned int *DWT_CYCCNT = (unsigned int *)0xE0001004; //address of the register
        volatile unsigned int *DWT_CONTROL = (unsigned int *)0xE0001000; //address of the register
        volatile unsigned int *SCB_DEMCR = (unsigned int *)0xE000EDFC; //address of the register

        *SCB_DEMCR = *SCB_DEMCR | 0x01000000;
        *DWT_CYCCNT = 0; // reset the counter
        *DWT_CONTROL = *DWT_CONTROL | 1 ; // enable the counter

_DO_SOMETHING_HERE_

count = *DWT_CYCCNT;
         printf("\n COUNT!!!! = %d",*DWT_CYCCNT);
```

The value of `count` is "lost" when debugging the code.

Thanks

Comment: I think you will need to post some code. Try to simplify the code such that it's only a small [perhaps empty] loop in the middle of the code, rather than posting some complicated math - as that's not what we care about for this case anyways.

Comment: thanks for the response. code chunk added. :)

Comment: You do realize that debugging optimised code is regularly tricky - in particular, if count is not being used, it may be optimised away as a variable. I doubt there is much you can do about it - maybe make it a global variable, and ensure that it's initialized and read in some other function(s).

Comment: Why don't you print `*DWT_CYCCNT`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas tried it already. same thing happens when i do that.

Comment: do not debug optimized code.
optimization is treaky sometimes. You only write to count and never read it, try to print count, maybe compiler wont remove it. Why dont you check value in register (*DWT_CYCCNT) instead of count?

Comment: @AbhishekThakur: The compiler clearly did not remove `*DWT_CYCCNT` did it? If it removed `DWT_CYCCNT`, if it did, then get the address of the object that you used to initialize the pointer, then dump its contents. Yes, it is painful to debug optimized code, but you have to choose whether you want performance or easy debugging :)

Comment: I suppose just doing your `SOMETHING` a gazillion times and stopwatching it isn't good enough?

Comment: what do *lost* and *returns errors* mean?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas that works! when its not inline function the printf function is throwing values for *DWT_CYCCNT. Would you mind posting it as answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: @thang by 'lost' i mean '<value undefined>', by 'return errors' i mean something like 'error: -1214343314'

Comment: Can you try making count a global volatile? Also assign it to itself somewhere so you have both a read and write of it. Lastly, make sure you haven't turned off debug symbols somewhere while turning on optimizations!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure a period of time, you could use an oscilloscope. Simply set a pin to HIGH when entering the code section whose timing you want to measure and then set the pin to LOW when the section ends.

This is the most accurate way to measure timings in embedded.

Answer (score 0):

If your _DO_SOMETHING_HERE_ is not external operation not it contains volatile operations compiler is allowed to move it before/after volatile operations if it does not change program result.

Only volatile operations are ordered.

I use similar code for benchmarking, but i prefer global volatile for count (it worked for me with arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.6)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable with `__root` (double underscore) then IAR will not optimize it away.

```
__root volatile int count = 0;
```

You may still have other problems. Your `_DO_SOMETHING_HERE_` code could still be optimized out. You may need to use `__root` for other declarations also.

The other issue I see often is that the debugger doesn't show local variable values at times while using optimizations. You will need to open the Disassemble window the Registers window and see what register (somewhere between `R0-R12`) is used to store `count`. A foolproof way would be to have a function return your count value. ARM Cortex uses `R0` for return values, so after the function completes the value in `R0` is the value of count. Unfortunately this is what you have to do when debugging with optimizations.